Struggling with packing bit-fields in C++ struct
I was trying to make a nicer type for working with packed data being sent to an LED driver IC. The format looks like this. It shows two possible formats, depending on the value of the Address bit. Note that the MSB is shown at the right, not the left, and should be the first bit shifted into the IC:

I tried to write a union type that would cover this, but it kept expanding to 5 bytes. So I settled on trying to just write this:
struct Color {
    uint8_t     ignore  :   1;
    uint8_t     address :   1;
    uint16_t    red     :   10;
    uint16_t    green   :   10;
    uint16_t    blue    :   10;

    Color()
        :
        ignore(0),
        address(0),
        red(0),
        green(0),
        blue(0)
    {
    }
} __attribute__((packed));

Dumping the bytes in order from the start of the struct (on an M1 MacBook Pro, compiled with Clang, so little-endian) gives me:
Color c;
c.ignore = 1;
dump(&c, sizeof(c));

01 00 00 00 

I expected 80 00 00 00. If I put address and ignore at the end of the struct, I get 00 00 00 80, which is also unexpected.
Is it possible to write the type such that the bits are all packed into 4 bytes in the order expected? I realize there may also be an endianness issue in the assignment to the uint16_t values, but I think I can deal with that.

Why are you mixing uint8_t and uint16_t in the flags definition?

What does sizeof( struct Color ) return?

sizeof( struct Color ) returns 4. Is it an issue to mix uint8_t and uint16_t? I used the smallest type that would hold the values.

They should all be uint32_t because they're bitfields of a 32-bit number. And I would say you have the fields backwards. The first bit is bit 0, not bit 31. Reverse the positions and see if it becomes easier to deal with. You may still need some kind of htonl() but that may also depend on how your peripheral shift register works.

Making them all uint32_t didn't change the behavior. If I reverse the order of the fields, then it makes the ignore and address bits be the high bits of the last byte, as opposed to being the low bits of the first byte. Neither is correct.

Does this answer your question? C/C++: Force Bit Field Order and Alignment

We presume dump starts at the beginning of the pointer, and increments. You say the machine is little endian. Therefore, it begins with the LSB and proceeds to the MSB. Since the machine byte order is little endian, I would then expect the output of each bit to reflect little endian as well, so that setting the right-most bit of the right most byte results in setting the most significant bit. Wouldn't that be setting 0x80?

@Rick There's literally no standard way to lay out bit fields.  Given uint16_t    red     :   10; and then uint16_t    green   :   10;, there's no way to know if green shares part of a uint16_t with red or if they both get their own separate uint16_t variables as whether or not a bit field can span across multiple components - they're pretty much entirely "implementation-defined"

@jxh on big endian implementations for a byte and no guarantee of that for a bit-field Little endians and bigendian field order

@Swift-FridayPie The standard cannot predict how machines will layout bits within a byte. That is why it is implementation defined. But code using bit-fields in heterogenous endian environments have been interoperable for more than 50 years already.

@jxh and you know what I see when I look, let's say, into linux kernel, at least before v.4? there is use of endian.h an #ifndef to write same structure in opposite order. Bit-order depends on media used, order of packing fields into evey memory location is also implementation defined, because there are several bytes. Note, in ISO C only int was allowed as bit-fields type (GNU C was more lax). With predefined order of packing reflecting endian-ness. In C++ that's different and combining different storage types is allowed to do odd things.

@Swift-FridayPie My only point is that it is possible to create interoperable software using bit-fields. So "no guarantee" does not mean bit-fields cannot be effectively used, even if you have to check endianess.

@jxh yeah, if you're in control of platform. E.g. linux kernel code gets away with many UBs and implementation-defined code because, well.. it is THE implementation.

@Swift-FridayPie While there are many ABI specific code paths in the Linux kernel, endianess is stable. A MIPS based processor operating in little-endian mode and a little-endian Intel processor will have the same bit layout for an unsigned integral type of the same bit width. The standard cannot predict this will always be the case, so it is left as implementation defined. Yet interoperability is still there. Implementation defined does not necessarily mean the feature is not practical or useful.

You shouldn't use bit-fields for this, but rather bit-shifting and bit-masking. Sadly bit-fields are different from compiler to compiler and you can't rely on the correct order of bytes.
As stated by the C99 standard 6.7.2.1:10:

An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is
implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the
addressable storage unit is unspecified.


And there’s no set of pragmas or attributes to force GCC or Clang to pack in declaration order, I guess?

@Rick Nope, but there is might be a trick of exploiting rule about structs with common beginning in a union

@Rick with GCC #pragma pack(1) got a side-effect of fields beginning to straddle boundaries of memory locations. That's a behaviour at least partially shared by MSVC. There is no way to control order, if you have some RiSC or ARM target with big-endian arch, they will be in opposite order somehow.
